Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid for Apple Maps link on iPhone
Based on the Map links documentation "https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html"
I am trying to open map links from my app. When I tried on Safari with iPhone 15 pro iOS 17 and iPhone 12 iOS 17, I get a "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid". This is not working when clicking on the link within my app but also when entering the link directly in the browser bar.
http://maps.apple.com/  works
but
http://maps.apple.com/?q=Mexican+Restaurant does not work (this the first link example of the Apple doc)
The links work well on Safari with my iPad 5e gen pro (iOS 16) and my Mac Boo pro.
I tried with https:// and maps://maps.apple.com ... same result.
Has the doc changed? This one seems to be an archive.
How to do that?
Thanks
